# white space added in the beginning of new line when printing in new line

Tags: python-3.x, printing, output, whitespace

When I try to print whatever data on several lines using python 3, a single whitespace gets added to the beginning of all the lines except first one. for example:

```
[in] print('a','\n','b','\n','c')
```

the output will be:

```
a
 b
 c
```

but my desired output is:

```
a
b
c
```

so far I've only been able to do this by doing three print commands. Anyone has any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`
>
> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end.
>   sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword
>   arguments.

Calling `print('a', '\n', 'b')` will print each of those three items with a space in between, which is what you are seeing.

You can change the separator argument to get what you want:

```
print('a', 'b', sep='\n')
```

Also see the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.